# Storm Topology not submit

Tags: java, log4j, rabbitmq, slf4j, apache-storm

i have configured my machine zookeeper,nimbus,supervisor are running properly and my topology working in LocalCluster

```
LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
cluster.submitTopology("SendPost", conf, builder.createTopology());
Utils.sleep(10000000000l);
cluster.killTopology("SendPost");
cluster.shutdown();
```

now i want try submit my topology bt it not working

```
/usr/local/storm/bin$ ./storm jar /home/winoria/Desktop/Storm/storm-starter/target/storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.winoria.post.PostTopology Post
```

i getting following error

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/storm/lib/logback-classic-1.0.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/winoria/Desktop/Storm/storm-starter/target/storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
Running: java -client -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/usr/local/storm -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /usr/local    /storm/storm-netty-0.9.0.1.jar:/usr/local/storm/storm-console-logging-0.9.0.1.jar:/usr/local/storm/storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/httpcore-4.1.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/carbonite-1.5.0.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/mockito-all-1.9.5.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/jgrapht-0.8.3.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/ring-jetty-adapter-0.3.11.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/jzmq-2.1.0.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/asm-4.0.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/logback-core-1.0.6.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/tools.nrepl-0.2.3.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/compojure-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/ring-devel-0.3.11.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/httpclient-4.1.1.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/commons-exec-1.1.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/guava-13.0.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/clout-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.5.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/clojure-1.4.0.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/hiccup-0.3.6.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/clj-stacktrace-0.2.2.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/tools.logging-0.2.3.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/ring-core-1.1.5.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/zookeeper-3.3.3.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/math.numeric-tower-0.0.1.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/disruptor-2.10.1.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/minlog-1.2.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/core.incubator-0.1.0.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/ring-servlet-0.3.11.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/clj-time-0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/tools.cli-0.2.2.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/logback-classic-1.0.6.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/kryo-2.17.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/joda-time-2.0.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/curator-client-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/libthrift7-0.7.0-2.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/tools.macro-0.1.0.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/clojure-complete-0.2.3.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/junit-3.8.1.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/winoria/Desktop/Storm/storm-starter/target/storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:/usr/local/storm/conf:/usr/local/storm/bin -Dstorm.jar=/home/winoria/Desktop/Storm/storm-starter/target/storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.winoria.post.PostTopology Post
SLF4J: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError. 
SLF4J: See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop for more details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:39)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:43)
at com.rapportive.storm.spout.AMQPSpout.<clinit>(AMQPSpout.java:67)
at com.winoria.post.PostTopology.main(PostTopology.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-    log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop for more details.
at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.<clinit>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:49)
... 4 more
```

plz help me ...........
thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used cassandra and cassandra-all version 1.6.1 declares both log4j and slf4j-log4j12 as compile-time dependencies so I add following dependencies and my topology work like charm !!!

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId> org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
<artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
<version>1.1.6</version>

<exclusions>
  <exclusion> 
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
  <exclusion> 
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
</exclusions> 

</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to exclude either **log4j-over-slf4j.jar** or **slf4j-log4j12.jar** from your classpath. I don't know which build tool do you use. Check the documentation of your build tool to see how to exclude a dependency.

For more reference: [Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop)

Answer (score 1):

You have to exclude all occurrences of `slf4j-log4j12.jar` . . . It doesn't work if you exclude all occurrences of `log4j-over-slf4j.jar` because Apache Storm adds `log4j-over-slf4j` at runtime (through the `storm-core` dependency in your `pom.xml`). Even when I added `exclude log4j-over-slf4j` to the `storm-core` dependency it would still be brought back at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If after exclude either log4j-over-slf4j.jar or slf4j-log4j12.jar , you still got this error. See in your jar, if both these two classes exist: org.slf4j.impl.log4jloggerfactory and org.apache.log4j.log4jloggerfactory .
And then find if any other jars besides slf4j and log4j contains these two classes.
In my situation， there is org.slf4j.impl.log4jloggerfactory in activemq. The error log really mislead me for a long time.